# Index out of bounds after reading a text file

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have the following simple code, and I tried to use one of the indices from the .txt file. The index that I want is at `(4,1)` while the size of my matrix in the .txt file is `(8,4)`. When I run the code, MATLAB give me the following error;

Attempted to access `q(4,1);` index out of
bounds because `size(q)=[1,601]`

Can someone help me understand why I receive the error and how to fix it?

Here is the code:

```
q = fileread('sv11edit.txt');
toe = q(4,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on the format of the file `sv11edit.txt`.  However, `fileread` returns a string of characters.  In this case, it gives you a string that is 601 characters long.  You receive an error because you assume that `q` is 8 by 4, but this is not the case.

Check what is being stored in `q` before you try anything like the second line of your code.  The function `load` may be a better alternative to `fileread`.